# Calling a webservice from Android app

Tags: android, web-services

I have a link like http://1.2.3.4:8080/csmmobileapi/service.asmx where in i am suppose to add my link as a webservice and create an object for the service in the app then call through that object ,but i am blank on how to achieve this,can anyone help me to understand this and share few examples.

This call will return me a xml data.

Comment: The Ion library is a good start. http://goo.gl/AGx9Q The library itself is pretty good for asynchronously loading data from a web server, and their documentation and examples on GitHub could help you get started.

Comment: wanted to know it isnt possible to use httpconnection for this?

Comment: Retrofit (http://goo.gl/OTAIUX) is another good solution to make HTTP requests easier to implement

Comment: but for this i need to make use of there jar file ?

Comment: Between being a duplicate and too broad, there are plenty reasons to close this question.

Comment: @pihu It is possible, but it might also be an unnecessary effort. Ion and Retrofit both handle the HTTP request for you so you can work on a higher level (i.e. your business logic).